# detect when mouse hovers/leaves a tkinter canvas element that moves by itself, because the canvas element moved, not the mouse

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a program with a canvas text element that moves around. I use tag_bind to detect when a mouse hovers and leaves the element. It fails when the element itself moves into or away from the mouse.

```py
import math
class Easing:
    @staticmethod
    def linear(t, b, c, d):
        return c*t/d + b
    @staticmethod
    def inSine(t, b, c, d):
        return -c * math.cos(t/d * (math.pi/2)) + c + b

def apply_easing(easing, t, beginning, destination, duration):
    #TODO: make this more efficient if possible
    return {key: easing(t, beginning[key], destination[key] - beginning[key], duration) for key in destination.keys()}

class Tween:
    easing = Easing()
    _playing = []
    def __init__(self, duration, subject, target, easing=easing.linear, options={"loop":"forever"}):
        self.duration = duration
        self.subject = subject
        self.target = target
        self.initial = {key: self.subject[key] for key in self.target.keys()}
        self.easing = easing
        self.loop = options.get("loop", "once") if options is not None else "once"
        self.playbackdirection = "forward"
        self.elapsed_time = 0
        self.play()

    def play(self):
        if not self in Tween._playing:
            Tween._playing.append(self)

    def stop(self):
        Tween._playing.remove(self)
        
    def update(self, deltatime):
        if self.elapsed_time >= self.duration:
            if self.loop == "once":
                self.stop()

            if self.loop == "forever":
                self.playbackdirection = "backward"

        if self.elapsed_time <= 0:
            self.playbackdirection = "forward"

        if self.playbackdirection == "forward":
            self.elapsed_time += deltatime
        elif self.playbackdirection == "backward":
            self.elapsed_time -= deltatime

        result = apply_easing(self.easing, self.elapsed_time, 
            self.initial, 
            self.target, 
            self.duration)
        self.subject.update(result)
        return result


from tkinter import *
import time

WIDTH=640
HEIGHT=480

root = Tk()
root.title("Minimal Example")
root.geometry(f"{WIDTH}x{HEIGHT}")

class InteractiveText:
    def __init__(self, canvas, x, y, content, default_fill='black'):
        self.position = {"x":x, "y":y}
        self.content = content
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.default_fill = default_fill
        self.text = canvas.create_text(self.position["x"], self.position["y"], text=self.content, font = ("monaco", 24), fill=default_fill)
        self.canvas.tag_bind(self.text, '<Enter>', lambda event: self.on_hover())
        self.canvas.tag_bind(self.text, '<Leave>', lambda event: self.on_leave())
        self.canvas.tag_bind(self.text, '<Button-1>', self.on_click)

    def update_position(self):
        self.canvas.coords(self.text, self.position["x"], self.position["y"])

    def on_hover(self):        
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.text, fill="red")

    def on_leave(self):
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.text, fill=self.default_fill)

    def on_click(self, event):
        print(self.content, "clicked!")


class Scene:
    def __init__(self):
        self.canvas = Canvas(root, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, bg="white")
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.canvas_items = []
    def text(self, x, y, content):
        t = InteractiveText(self.canvas, x, y, content)
        self.canvas_items.append(t)
        return t
    def rect(self, x, y, w, h):
        r = MyRect(self.canvas, x, y, w, h)
        self.canvas_items.append(r)
        return r

def update(lastFrameTime):
    currentTime = time.time()
    for tw in Tween._playing:
        tw.update(currentTime - lastFrameTime)
    for obj in CURRENT_SCENE.canvas_items:
        obj.update_position()

    next_deltatime = int(round(lastFrameTime + 1/60*1000 - currentTime, 0))

    root.after(next_deltatime, update, currentTime)

root.after(0, update, time.time())


mainmenu =Scene()
CURRENT_SCENE = mainmenu

# There are the buttons for the Main Menu
playtext = mainmenu.text(-100, 65, "Play game")
quittext = mainmenu.text(WIDTH+150, 150, "Quit")

Tween(4.99, playtext.position, {"x": WIDTH/2+25, "y":50},  Tween.easing.linear)
Tween(4.99, quittext.position, {"x": WIDTH/2, "y":390}, Tween.easing.inSine)

root.mainloop()
```

I know the program is a little long for a SO quesiton but its mostly boilerplate. The important part is in the InteractiveText class, where I bind the mouse events to the canvas item. When the canvas item leaves the mouse behind on its own, it doesn't trigger a hover/leave event and thus doesn't trigger the functions on_leave and on_hover.

Expected hover to end after element coords changed so that the mouse was outside the element.

Comment: you could add all import so we could simply copy and run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to user 22536453 Undefined for making me realize i could bind the motion event to store the last known mouse position and then manually call hover/leave every tick. However, i also decided to try using .move instead of .coords to set the position, and:

- .move can use deltaX and deltaY instead of an absolute XY coordinate to place a object. Which is useful, but obvious.
- non-obviously, if you call move on another canvas item, tkinter seems to automatically figure out that the mouse has left the bounding box of another item that was moved using coords. It is unknown if there are any limitations there are to this, but you can test it in the program by hovering the mouse over the play game text, seeing it turn red, and then it turning black again after it updates the canvas, but if you comment out the quittext move line, it doesn't do that. pretty interesting.

Why is this important? mainly, I don't want to write a collision and bounds checking manager class for tkinter, when I was specifically lead to believe I could use tkinter so I wouldn't have to do that boilerplate.

```py
from tkinter import *
import time


WIDTH=640
HEIGHT=480

root = Tk()
root.title("minimum")
root.geometry(f"{WIDTH}x{HEIGHT}")

canvas = Canvas(root, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, bg="white")
canvas.pack()

playtext = canvas.create_text(200, 100, text="Play Game", font = ("monaco", 24), fill="black")
quittext = canvas.create_text(200, 200, text="Quit", font = ("monaco", 24), fill="black")

canvas.tag_bind(playtext, '<Enter>', lambda event: on_hover(playtext))
canvas.tag_bind(playtext, '<Leave>', lambda event: on_leave(playtext))
canvas.tag_bind(quittext, '<Enter>', lambda event: on_hover(quittext))
canvas.tag_bind(quittext, '<Leave>', lambda event: on_leave(quittext))

def on_hover(canvasitem):        
    canvas.itemconfig(canvasitem, fill="red")

def on_leave(canvasitem):
    canvas.itemconfig(canvasitem, fill="black")

print("Note: Coords refer to bounding box and not the XY position that an element is placed at. for example, if i place font=(\"monaco\", 24) text at (200,200), its bounding box = Coords: (114, 82, 287, 118) ")
tickcount = 0

# canvas.move(quittext, 1, -1)
def update():
    global tickcount
    tickcount += 1
    currentTime = time.time()
    # x1,y1,x2,y2 = canvas.bbox(playtext)
    # print(f"Prev Coords: {x1,y1,x2,y2}")

    dx = 10
    dy = 10
    canvas.coords(playtext, 200 + dx * tickcount, 100 + dy/2*tickcount)
    canvas.move(quittext, dx, -dy)
    # canvas.update_idletasks()  # Force update of the display

    # print(f"New Coords calculation (deltaX,deltaY={dx,dy}): {x1-dx, y1-dy}")
    # print(f"New Coords actuality 1: {canvas.bbox(playtext)}")

    root.after(1000, update)

root.after(1000, update)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: mark this answer as right with the green tick

Answer (score 1):

I have not got the most definitive solution but this is the best I could do. This solution should mean that we can get rid of these lines:

```
self.canvas.tag_bind(self.text, '<Enter>', lambda event: self.on_hover())
self.canvas.tag_bind(self.text, '<Leave>', lambda event: self.on_leave())
```

But I kept them in as while this code works great for the "Quit" for whatever reason the bounding box on the "Play game" is very small (its actually just the y dimension that is small). And hence it only highlights if the ycoordinate of the cursor is in the exact middle.

```
    def __init__(self, canvas, x, y, content, default_fill='black'):
        self.position = {"x":x, "y":y}
        self.content = content
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.default_fill = default_fill
        self.text = canvas.create_text(self.position["x"], self.position["y"], text=self.content, font = ("monaco", 24), fill=default_fill)
        self.canvas.tag_bind(self.text, '<Enter>', lambda event: self.on_hover())
        self.canvas.tag_bind(self.text, '<Leave>', lambda event: self.on_leave())
        self.canvas.tag_bind(self.text, '<Button-1>', self.on_click)
        self.canvas.bind('<Motion>', lambda event: self.motion(event))
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        
    def motion(self,e):
        self.x,self.y = e.x,e.y
    def update_position(self):
        x1,y1,x2,y2 =self.canvas.bbox(self.text)
        self.canvas.coords(self.text, self.position["x"], self.position["y"])
        if x1<self.x<x2 and y1<self.y<y2:
            self.on_hover()
        else:
            self.on_leave()
```

the main change to the code is adding the motion event inorder to get the last coordinates of the mouse stored in class attributes x,y. And the use of bbox() to get the bounding box of the text.

Comment: Thanks. I think you can only bind motion to one callback event, not multiple. If there's a way to do it, i;m not aware - im a tkinter newbie. example:
    def motion(self,e):
        print(f"set mouse position of {self.content} to {(e.x, e.y)}")
        self.x,self.y = e.x,e.y
output: <set mouse position of Quit to (527, 444)> but not set mouse position of Play game to (527, 444)>
your code is still useful! now i should be able to just bind motion once to the canvas and then call hover/leave manually for each canvas item ala for obj in Scene.canvas_items: obj.update_position

Comment: ```def motion(self,e):
        print(f"set mouse position of {self.content} to {(e.x, e.y)}") ```